# Seconds to minutes in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Unfortunately, the seconds to minute calculation using the `parseInt()` function isn't working with VueJS for me. I used the following to calculate minute from seconds:

`parseInt(this.seconds / 60, 10) % 60`

However, `this.seconds` value always returns `0` after `59` seconds, not `60` and as such the `parseInt()` function always returns `0`. I am out of luck now. Below is the full code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0
    },
    methods: {
        timer() {
            setInterval(() => {
                this.seconds = ++this.seconds % 60
                this.seconds = parseInt(this.seconds / 60, 10) % 60
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This data conversion is pure js, it has nothing to vue.js.

Comment: You're right. I think I figured it out. I shouldn't change the actual `seconds` value to calculate it with the `minutes`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by myself. I was changing the original `seconds` value which was causing the issue to calculate the `minutes. So, I used a different variable to store the loop count and calculate minute:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0,
        counter : 0
    },
    methods: {
        timer() {
            setInterval(() => {
                this.seconds = ++this.counter % 60
                this.minutes = parseInt(this.counter / 60, 10) % 60
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe replace `this.seconds` with this shorthand expression?

```
this.seconds === 0 ? 60 : this.seconds
```